# Time series in panda

Tags: javascript, c#, python, jupyter-notebook, time-series

How do I convert  a `date index` into *Time-based indexin*g?
so that i can later generate a month, weekday and a year

I tried this code

```
df['TRANS_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TRANS_DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

but after I change it to Index the date revert back to show as object

Comment: Please add a sample of the data before and after your code. Also, remove the `javascript` and `c#` tags, as they have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020170721 this is what i am getting, which i think is not the expected outcome

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you leave out the format option (letting it run to Default)? Also, it would be best if you show your original data.

Additional information - 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Hi. With a little time and a few good questions and answers, you would be able to use the "comment" section for suggestions and requests. In the meanwhile, please avoid using the "answer" section for those matters, as it marks to others that the question was answered.

Comment: Well, I wasn't allowed to comment on the initial question. It was incomplete. This was the only way of doing so. Anyway. Seems like I am rapidly running out of reputation points. :D